# No se puede leer la propiedad 'addEventListener' de null

Tags: javascript

Cuando ejecuto mi código, en la consola me devuelve:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

```js
function calcularPromedio(json) {
  var out = "-----------Calcultar Nota Promedio----------<br>";
  var i;
  var acumulador = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    acumulador += json[i].nota;
  }

  var promedio = acumulador / json.length;

  alert("La nota promedio es: " + promedio);

}

document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  calcularPromedio(estudiantes);
});
```

```html
<button id="notaPromedio">Mostrar Nota Promedio</button>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal y cómo puedo corregirlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes ningún elemento `html` con el *atributo* `id` llamado *boton1*, tienes un botón con el *atributo* `id` llamado *notaPromedio* por lo tanto deberías cambiar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```js
function calcularPromedio(json) {
  var out = "-----------Calcultar Nota Promedio----------<br>";
  var i;
  var acumulador = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    acumulador += json[i].nota;
  }

  var promedio = acumulador / json.length;

  alert("La nota promedio es: " + promedio);

}

// cambia boton1 por notaPromedio en el selector
document.getElementById("notaPromedio").addEventListener("click", function() {
  calcularPromedio(estudiantes);
});
```

```html
<button id="notaPromedio">Mostrar Nota Promedio</button>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorius,

Comment: @Gustavo si te ha sido útil mi respuesta recuerda marcala como aceptada, nos beneficiamos los dos :D